# PHP code to display Registered Date & Last Visited Date?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, user

How can I make a PHP script that displays a users *Registered Date* and *Last Visited Date* as it appears in the core Joomla profile page?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before asking a question like this, please do some research. Seeing as you have been doing a lot of work with the user Object already, I'm surprised you haven't seen the following page yet:

http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

You can simply use:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo '<p>Register date: ' . $user->registerDate . '</p>';
echo '<p>Last visited: ' . $user->lastvisitDate . '</p>';
```

Comment: i am quite lazy! :)

Comment: @Lodder I am suddenly horrified to find that I have 61 declined flags.  The one above is just one of the many that are rightfully removed from this site.  I suspect that most of them are my flagging of useless comments like "thanks", "your welcome", "I love you", "you are a genius", "i am quite lazy", etc.  What possible reason can there be for declining these flags?

Comment: @mickmackusa - The majority of your comment flags have been on "thank you" comments which I personally deem ok, as they show a sign of appreciation. Some of them however, I have deleted as they were replies to a comment which had been deleted for whatever reason and thus made no sense.

Comment: You are of course welcome to ask about this on Meta and get the opinion of the other moderators, as they may think differently.

Comment: You are one of two active moderators, right?

Comment: @mickmackusa 1/3 - https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators