# How to SET "lastvisitDate" for a Joomla user

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I am developing a mobile app which uses Joomla as the backend.
So far I am able to get the user object through

```
$user = JFactory::getUser($id);
```

However, each time a user visits the app, I want it to set the **lastvisitDate**.

I have seen this erlated Doc [JUser Class](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUser.html) but I don't know how to use it. I will be glad if anyone can be of help - Thank you.

Comment: See http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/php-code-to-display-registered-date-last-visited-date and http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/last-visit-date-override. They may be of some help.

Comment: Does the user login to the app using their Joomla credentials? If so, this information is already stored in the user object

Comment: Agreed with @Lodder, If your user logs into the site it will automatically update the database with the last visit information. From there you can query that info if you want to display it back to the user for some reason.

Comment: It is a mobile app running on Android which is using Joomla as the backend; and uses Ajax to interact with Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this based on my comment.

`lastvisitDate` is already stored in the `JUser`, object so you can access it like so:

```
$id   = 1;
$user = JFactory::getUser($id);
echo $user->lastvisitDate;
```